# "Запросил встречи" или "попросил о встрече"?

Tags: выбор-слов, фразеология

Как лучше сказать: "запросил встречи" или "попросил о встрече"? Текст художественный, то есть не формальный, но и не разговорный.

Ясно, что можно сказать и так, и так, но я хотел бы понять тонкости употребления.